# Changing Resolution of Disconnected (hidden) "Miracast" Monitor

Tags: display, resolution, external-display, display-settings, miracast

I had successfully set up a FireTV Cube to act as a wireless display for Windows, however, the default resolution wasn't correct. I changed it to 1080p and was successful, then for some reason I decided to push it further to 1920x1200 and that is when it stopped working. Unbeknown to me at the time, it *appeared* to be working when I accepted the changes, then I shortly realized that the screen was just frozen.

Now every time I attempt to reconnect it will immediately disconnect before I have the chance to change the resolution back to one that works. I've attempted to delete the drivers and scan the registry for "Amazon", "Non-PnP", and "miracast" for any value that might contain a 1200h resolution and just can't seem to figure out how I can reset this device. Here are the two devices that I tried uninstalling (they are only visible with the "show hidden" option checked):

[image]

Even after deleting the drivers I could find, it still defaults to the 1920x1200 when I attempt to re-add it, which I was able to confirm by recording a split second of it appearing in the display settings (you can see the height of monitor 2 is slightly larger than 1, which 1 is set to 1080)

[image]
<sup>*Apologize for the bad quality. I first attempted to capture this with Nvidia GeForce, but it stops recording as soon as the display settings changes (such as when it briefly adds the 2nd display)*</sup>

Is there a registry setting that is storing this display's resolution that I can change? A config file somewhere? I've already tried looking in Nvidia's CP but didn't find anything.

Comment: What does the NVIDIA Control Panel show as the resolution of the device? Same for *Settings > System > Display*?

Comment: @harrymc NVIDIA's CP doesn't show the wireless display at all. It's only [showing the active monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXI5.png), which is set to 1920x1080. System Display settings [is the same story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCWR6.png).

Comment: Do you change the resolution [this way](https://www.supportyourtech.com/streaming/how-to-change-the-display-resolution-on-the-amazon-fire-tv-stick/)?